# Merge two query results

Tags: postgresql

I have two databases (postgres) that are absolutely the same. Now, I was wondering if there is some way to do the following:

```
$res1 = pg_query($connFirstDatabase, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$res2 = pg_query($connSecondDatabase, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
```

`$result = merged res1 and res2;` //I wonder if there is a way to do this, cause later on I have a working php code which takes care of the $result variable.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I did search if this question already exist, and didn't find a related answer. Also, it would be enough if someone just gives me a tick in right direction to look for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two arrays, using pg_fetch_all(), and use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to combine both arrays.